# Continuity of improper integral

Tags: real-analysis

> $$f(x)=\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\cos t}{t^2+x^2}\, dt  $$ continuous and bounded????

I think it's bounded since $$\left|\frac{\cos t}{t^2+x^2} \right| \le \frac{1}{t^2+x^2}, 1\le t < \infty $$ but what about continuous.?????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The estimate

$$\tag{*}\left|\frac{\cos t}{x^2+t^2}\right| \leqslant \frac{1}{t^2}$$

proves uniform convergence of the improper integral by the Weierstrass test. This along with continuity of the integrand for $(x,t) \in \mathbb{R}\times [1, \infty)$implies continuity of $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Defining the sequence of functions,

$$f_n(x) = \int_1^n \frac{\cos t}{x^2+t^2} \, dt,$$

we have $f_n \to f$ uniformly.  Since the $f_n$ are continuous it follows by a well-known theorem that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Note also that the inequality (*) implies boundedness, since for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

$$\left|\int_1^\infty \frac{\cos t}{x^2+t^2}\, dt\right| \leqslant \int_1^\infty\frac{dt}{t^2} = 1$$